# Android SQLite: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException when retrieving a row from a table?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I keep getting **android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1** exception when trying to get a single row from a Sqlite table using a **ID** value.

Why do you think this happens? What is wrong with my code?

```
public Product getProduct(DBOps dop, String productId) {

        Product p = new Product();
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT " + TableInfo.PID + " FROM "
  + TableInfo.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE pid="+"'"+productId+"'"; 
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor CR = SQ.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);

        try
        {
            if(CR.getCount() > 0)
            {
                while (!CR.isAfterLast()) {
                    p.PID = CR.getString(0);
                    p.NAME = CR.getString(1);
                    p.SIZE = CR.getString(2);
                    p.COLORS = CR.getString(3);
                    p.DESC = CR.getString(4);
                    p.PRICE= CR.getString(5);
                    p.OUTLETS = CR.getString(6);
                    p.FABRIC = CR.getString(7);
                    p.QUANTITY = CR.getString(8);
                    p.CATEGORY = CR.getString(9);
                    p.RATING = CR.getString(10);

                    CR.moveToNext();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CR.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("DBOps Error", "Look at DBOps Class's getProduct Method");
            Log.e("DBOps Error", ex.toString());
        }
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested,
>   with a size of 1

Because you are currently selecting only one column from table which is `TableInfo.PID` but trying to retrieve more then one column from cursor.

So  change select query by specify all columns in select query or use `* FROM` get all columns:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM "
  + TableInfo.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE pid="+"'"+productId+"'";
```

Comment: Oh.. that makes sense. What changes should I make?

Answer (score 2):

***Use Like This***

```
  if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())

        { do

        {
         //your code 
        }
while(cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        }
        }
```

Hope it will helps u

Answer (score 1):

You need to call cursor.moveToFirst() before using the cursor.  This moves it to row 0.  Make sure to check the return value-  if it returns false then it could not move to row 0 for some reason (generally it means 0 rows returned).

Comment: So this CR.moveToFirst(); should be added before the while loop or before my if condition? :)

Comment: Either location will work, I think.  But you need to do it before requesting any row data.